# In httpclient 4.x.x, when we configure PoolingClientConnectionManager to httpclient, do we need to release connection manually?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

## Env：

- Java 6
- Apache HttpClient 4.2.3

## Question Detail:

Following httpclient manual, when I use ***DefaultHttpClient*** without configuring any connection manager. we need to let connection manager shutdown.

But when I have many requests on many servers, I will configure PoolingClientConnectionManager as connection manager. I don't find any reference on the Apache site for this case - **should I do something to release connections for a specific httpclient request? or the httpclient will do it automatically in framework level?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do. Connection managers allocate available connections to individual requests but they have no way of knowing whether or not a particular connection is still in use. When processing a response HttpClient only reads message head into memory while message content is streamed directly from the underlying connection. It is a responsibility of the consumer to trigger connection release back to the manager by closing the content input stream associated with the response object.

Comment: I read the source code of httpclient in ___DefaultRequestDirector___, it seems that it will deal with connection closing stuff. I am not sure of it for I cannot find the sure reference in its offical documentation. httpclient project changes too fast so that the docs is slower than source code. Can you find some sure/official reference of it?

Comment: Please see http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e139 and http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientConnectionRelease.java. With HC 4.3 one can also use Java 7 'try with resources' to ensure connection release and resource deallocation http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientConnectionRelease.java

Comment: I am using 4.2.3, the guide (4.3-dev) seems do not solve my problem.

Comment: What is _specifically_ the problem you are having? HttpClient _does not_ automatically release connections. One _must_ close input stream associated with the response message to make that happen _regardless_ of the version

Comment: My question is the title. I think I don't know what to do in case of PoolingClientConnectionManager

Comment: Which I have answered and also provided you with the references to the official documentation

Comment: if i `call httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();`, what will happens? you think it is ok for me?  and waht's more, there are no httpclient.close and httpreponse.close in 4.2.x。